# MarkLogic: Using aggregate functions in SPARQL queries

Tags: sparql, marklogic, semantics

I found the following query in the marklogic study material:

```
PREFIX mo: <http://mlu.marklogic.com/ontology/> 
SELECT ?country ?max 
FROM <http://mlu.marklogic.com/populations> 
WHERE { 
        { 
          SELECT (MAX(?pop) as ?max) 
          WHERE {?country mo:population ?pop} 
        } 
        { 
          ?country mo:population ?pop . ?country mo:population ?max 
        }
}
```

I replaced it with:

```
select ?country ?max
from <http://mlu.marklogic.com/populations>
where{
    {
      select (MAX(?pop) as ?max)
      where {?country mo:population ?pop}
    }
    {?country mo:population ?max}
  }
```

It seems both the queries return the same result. So is the and statement in the first query of any importance? am I missing out anything ?

Answer (score 3):

It's actually kind of a strange example, and the difference isn't obvious, but there is one.  First let's get some sample data, and we'll include one country that has multiple population values.

### Sample Data

```
@prefix : <urn:ex:>

:a :pop 200 .
:b :pop 300 .
:c :pop 400 .
:d :pop 500 . # d has two population values
:d :pop 600 .
:e :pop 400 .
:f :pop 600 . # f also has a maximum population
```

### Your Query

Now, with your query, you'll get back the countries that happen to have the maximum population as their value.  There may be more than one of these.  You're matching the triple **?country :population MAX_POPULATION**, and for each ?country and MAX_POPULATION, that triple is either there or it isn't. RDF doesn't have "duplicate triples", or anything like that, so each ?country is either in or out.

```sql
prefix : <urn:ex:>

select ?c ?max {
  { select (max(?pop) as ?max) { ?c :pop ?pop } }
  { ?c :pop ?max }
}
```

```
------------
| c  | max |
============
| :f | 600 |
| :d | 600 |
------------
```

### Their Query

Now, with their query, you'll still get each of the countries that has the maximum population, but there's an extra variable in play.  Even though **?country :population MAX_POPULATION** has only one way to match, **?country :population ?population** may have more ways.

```sql
prefix : <urn:ex:>

select ?c ?max {
  { select (max(?pop) as ?max) { ?c :pop ?pop } }
  { ?c :pop ?max . ?c :pop ?pop }
}
```

```
------------
| c  | max |
============
| :f | 600 |
| :d | 600 |
| :d | 600 |
------------
```

Comment: That's the only and perfect answer! Conclusion: the example query is strange and should be changed to the one with the single triple pattern. Cheers